# flutter pull up to refetch data from api

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use Refresh indicator so that when you pull up the page you are in right now rebuilds i will share with you my code i have tried many times but really i can't find a straight way around it here is my code

```
  class Companies {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String companyLogo;

  Companies({this.id, this.name, this.companyLogo});

  factory Companies.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Companies(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
      companyLogo: json['company_logo'],
    );
  }
}

Future<List<Companies>> fetchCompanies() async {
  final response = await http.get('$webSiteUrl/company/api/fetch');
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return parseCompanies(response.body);
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load the companies');
  }
}


List<Companies> parseCompanies(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  return parsed.map<Companies>((json) => Companies.fromJson(json)).toList();
}
    class CompaniesPage extends StatefulWidget{
      @override
      _CompaniesState createState() => _CompaniesState();
    }
    
    class _CompaniesState extends State<CompaniesPage> {
      var refreshKey = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();
    
      Future<List<Companies>> companies;
      @override
    
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        companies = fetchCompanies();
      }
    
      Future<Null> refreshCompanies() async {
        refreshKey.currentState?.show(atTop: false);
        setState(() {
          companies = fetchCompanies();
        });
    
        return await companies;
      }
    
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        checkVersion(context);
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
                child: FutureBuilder<List<Companies>>(
                  future: companies,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      List<Companies> companies = snapshot.data;
                      if(companies.length >= 1){
                        return MainLayout(
                          RefreshIndicator(
                            key: refreshKey,
                            onRefresh: refreshCompanies,
                            child: GridView.count(
                              crossAxisCount: 2 ,
                              children: List.generate(companies.length, (index) {
                                return GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () => {
                                    Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Categories(companies[index].id, companies[index].name)),
                                    )},
                                  child: CompaniesInterface(companies[index].id , companies[index].name , companies[index].companyLogo),
                                );
                              }),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }else{
                        return EmptyDataBase();
                      }
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return ConnectionError();
                    }
    
                    // By default, show a loading spinner.
                    return DefaultTabController(
                      length: 1,
                      child: TabBar(
                        indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
                        tabs: <Widget>[
                          Tab(
                            child: LoadingBouncingGrid.square(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
                              size: 40,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
        );
      }
    }
```

as you can see i have tested it but it isn't refreshing the page correctly what i want is how should i rebuild this page on pull up so the missing part from my code i think is `refreshCompanies()` function

Update :

```
class _CompaniesState extends State<CompaniesPage> {
  StreamController<List<Companies>> companiesStreamController;
  var refreshKey = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();

  Future<List<Companies>> fetchCompanies() async {
    final response = await http.get('$webSiteUrl/company/api/fetch');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
      // then parse the JSON.
      return parseCompanies(response.body);
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      throw Exception('Failed to load the companies');
    }
  }

  loadCompanies() async {
    fetchCompanies().then((result) async {
      companiesStreamController.add(result);
      return result;
    });
  }

  Future<Null> refreshCompanies() async {
    refreshKey.currentState.show(atTop: true);
    setState(() {
      loadCompanies();
    });
  }
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    checkVersion(context);
    companiesStreamController = new StreamController();
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_) => loadCompanies());
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder<List<Companies>>(
          stream: companiesStreamController.stream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              List<Companies> companies = snapshot.data;
              if(companies.length >= 1){
                return MainLayout(
                  RefreshIndicator(
                    onRefresh: refreshCompanies,
                    key: refreshKey,
                    child: GridView.count(
                      crossAxisCount: 2 ,
                      children: List.generate(companies.length, (index) {
                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () => {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Categories(companies[index].id, companies[index].name)),
                            )},
                          child: CompaniesInterface(companies[index].id , companies[index].name , companies[index].companyLogo),
                        );
                      }),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }else{......rest of code
```

Comment: In `refreshCompanies` add `await` before `fetchCompanies()` and remove last line.

Comment: not working
error: A value of type 'List<Companies>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Future<List<Companies>>'.

Comment: Sorry I thought companies was a list. You'll need to use a StreamBuilder instead of a FutureBuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `StreamController`:

```
StreamController<List<Companies>> dataController;
```

Initialize it in your `initState`:

```
dataController = StreamController();
```

Move fetchCompanies inside your widget and before returning the result add it to your stream:

```
var result = parseCompanies(response.body);
dataController.add(result);
```

Use a `StreamBuilder` instead of `FutureBuilder`:

```
StreamBuilder<List<Companies>>(
  stream: dataController.stream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
     ...
  }
)
```

Comment: now i have working stream builder i will share my code but the refresh isn't working i want the refresh to rebuild Stream because for example if user fetches the companies and while the companies are loading (which usually takes about 1 sec) the internet interrupted then the user will be left with empty images so that the widget should get built again

Comment: you can see the problem here https://imgur.com/a/a9mHlFH in the red boxes it should be two more pages but as i mentioned when i refresh nothing really  happens

Comment: Update : it is working correctly but it isn't rebuilding so that the problem i have described earlier persists

Comment: Is the function refreshCompanies being called when you refresh?

Comment: You're not returning a future in this function, but it should refresh anyway.

Comment: yes it is being called and if there is any data has been deleted or new records have been added to the database it fetches them correctly, however it isn't rebuilding the entire widget so as i mentioned if it was interrupted it will show broken data just like the future builder

Comment: any ideas about this problem ?

Comment: Once you add data to the stream it will call the builder method and update its content.

Comment: Ok Thank you very much Mr.Sami

Comment: I can link you a sample dartpad.

Comment: Check it [here](https://dartpad.dev/4224bea7a9a2dae0177a20b716dadbf6)

Comment: it is working, i mean when you pull up it is updating the data so that if there is any addition or deletion it is updating the Ui correctly but  if the internet was on and you opened the app it will load the images and while loading them lets say you disconnected from the internet, What will happen ? there will be missing images like shown in the link i shared earlier what i want is when the user pulls up i want to rebuild the ui even if there weren't any changes so that those missing pictures will appear again

Comment: Try adding this line at the end of the refresh function:  `setState(() {refreshKey = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();});`, this will recreate the tree.

Comment: didn't work, let me explain more , you opened the app with the internet on now the app is loading the pictures now you turned off the internet now you have one or two images didn't complete their creation so now you should refresh the page to recreate them but when you refresh the page they still in the same state

Comment: never mind sir i really appreciate your effort and thank you very much for your time i will look into it

Comment: It depends on how you’re getting images, they could be cached.

Comment: Sure no problem