# Flutter Empty Spaces in Future Builder if you turned off network while fetching images

Tags: api, flutter, gridview

Hello there I have a simple app that fetches images from webserver and then shows them in grid view builder

what I am trying to do is on pull up rebuild all the images note that I have already implemented RefreshIndicator() and its function which is OnRefresh is working correctly whenever a change happens in database it will add the new image to the view,

I want it also to rebuild all images because imagine this situation with me :

you opened the app the future builder fetched the data and now it is showing them but while it is showing them you suddenly disconnected from the internet this will leave you with empty spaces(it was supposed to be images but now they are blank) so what I want to do is rebuilding these images on pull up so that if the user found any missing images he can just pull up to refresh the page and rebuild all images again

here is my code it is just the RefreshCompanies() that needs modification

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:app/exceptions/connection_error.dart';
import 'package:app/exceptions/empty_db.dart';
import 'package:app/reusable_widgets/interfaces/Companies/Companies_interface.dart';
import 'package:app/reusable_widgets/interfaces/LoadingIndicator.dart';
import 'package:app/reusable_widgets/interfaces/Main_Layout.dart';
import 'package:app/reusable_widgets/logic/Check_version.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'Categories.dart';
import 'package:app/reusable_widgets/globals.dart';

class Companies {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String companyLogo;

  Companies({this.id, this.name, this.companyLogo});

  factory Companies.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Companies(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
      companyLogo: json['company_logo'],
    );
  }
}

Future<List<Companies>> fetchCompanies() async {
  final response = await http.get('$webSiteUrl/company/api/fetch');
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return parseCompanies(response.body);
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load the companies');
  }
}


List<Companies> parseCompanies(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  return parsed.map<Companies>((json) => Companies.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

class CompaniesPage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _CompaniesState createState() => _CompaniesState();
}

class _CompaniesState extends State<CompaniesPage> {
  Future<List<Companies>> _companies;
  var refreshKey = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkVersion(context);
    _companies = fetchCompanies();
  }

  Future<Null> refreshCompanies() async{
    await DefaultCacheManager().emptyCache();
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)).then((value) =>
        setState(() {
          _companies = fetchCompanies();
        })
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<Companies>>(
          future: _companies,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              List<Companies> companies = snapshot.data;
              if(companies.length >= 1){
                return MainLayout(
                  RefreshIndicator(
                    onRefresh: refreshCompanies,
                    key: refreshKey,
                    child: GridView.count(
                      crossAxisCount: 2 ,
                      children: List.generate(companies.length, (index) {
                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () => {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Categories(companies[index].id, companies[index].name)),
                            )},
                          child: CompaniesInterface(companies[index].id , companies[index].name , companies[index].companyLogo),
                        );
                      }),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }else{
                return EmptyDataBase();
              }
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return ConnectionError();
            }

            // By default, show a loading spinner.
            return LoadingIndicator();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my Companies Interface

```
class CompaniesInterface extends StatelessWidget{
  final companyId;
  final companyName;
  final companyLogo;

  CompaniesInterface(this.companyId , this.companyName ,this.companyLogo);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      child : Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        height: DeviceInformation(context).height * 0.7,
        width: DeviceInformation(context).width * 0.9,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: NetworkImage('$webSiteUrl$companyLogo'),
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here you can find what I mean by empty spaces
[image: red boxes should be images]

as you can see from the code I tried calling EmptyCache() but it didn't rebuild the grid view

Suggested Solution : hot reload is doing the desired thing correctly if you can find a function to hot reload the app programmatically then i think this will solve the problem

**UPDATE :
for anyone who will come in the future with the same question
i am afraid that there is no direct answer to my question so that i awarded the best one from my point of view**

Comment: Why don't you use the Cached network image? It will give you flexibility to show loader for each image and save some bandwidth when you are reloading the page as it will cache the image for future use.Also, it gives you an error if the image fails to load and you can use it to update the UI accordingly.

Comment: i am considering using it but not now i will use it later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having empty space without internet connection, try to use [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) as Image widget, it give you more controls like placeholder (you can still show loading image if no connection):

```
CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/200x150",
  imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
          image: imageProvider,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          colorFilter:
              ColorFilter.mode(Colors.red, BlendMode.colorBurn)),
    ),
  ),
  placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
  errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
),
```

or you can even refresh every single image you want if no connection by using [flutter_advanced_networkimage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_advanced_networkimage):

```
TransitionToImage(
  image: AdvancedNetworkImage(url,
    loadedCallback: () {
      print('It works!');
    },
    loadFailedCallback: () {
      print('Oh, no!');
    },
    loadingProgress: (double progress) {
      print('Now Loading: $progress');
    },
  ),
  loadingWidgetBuilder: (_, double progress, __) => Text(progress.toString()),
  fit: BoxFit.contain,
  placeholder: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
  width: 400.0,
  height: 300.0,
  enableRefresh: true, // <-- Refresh button
);
```

Comment: it is a great way of doing it i will refactor my code soon using this method but sorry this doesn't answer the question this is an alternative but really thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

`FutureBuilder` will only run once. After the `Future` it tracks is completed it won't rebuild anymore. You would have to call `setState()` or convert it to a `Stream`, adding new data whenever the data is refreshed.

Comment: well the thing is i have already tried converting it to stream and adding that using setstate but it didn't do the trick because it only adds or deletes the data based on the database so stream didn't work and then i tried doing it with the future builder it did the same work it only remove deleted data and adds new data to the screen it didn't refresh the entire page

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't understand

Comment: consider this scenario with me for more clarification. user fetched the data and now the data is being displayed to him in the app , now I as a webmaster added some data in my server. Now the user pulled up and the app displayed the refresh indicator and used setState to add  the new data to the variable. What will happen is that the Future Builder or the Stream Builder will just fetch the new data and add them to the screen and it wouldn't rebuild any missing elements

Comment: Why wouldn't it rebuild missing elements? If you set up things correctly it will rebuild. You have to add the new data, the list of items in the server to the Stream, then the `StreamBuilder` will react and rebuild everything. You will probably need to use `Keys` to be sure that things are in order.

Comment: you might want to take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62604261/flutter-pull-up-to-refetch-data-from-api this question i asked before and its exactly as you are telling me to do if i have understand you correctly but even though the stream builder didn't rebuild

Comment: to be hones i don't know where and when to use Keys or even what are Keys but i might did it by accident so if you are sure about it please share some code and the reason why you think it will solve the problem , Thank you for your time

Comment: Read this article: https://medium.com/flutter/keys-what-are-they-good-for-13cb51742e7d in a nutshell Keys tell the Flutter Engine which items in a list have changed. The Flutter engine has a hard time figuring out which items to update on a list if the items have the same type and are a StatefulWidget.

Comment: well after reading that i think this could be one of the ways of doing it , but exactly how should i implement it ? , should i specify a unique key for each item in my list ? and if i do that then how should i rebuild the list again with new keys ?

Comment: Read the article, understand what are keys. Usually you can use unique keys, or use any unique id into your data as the key's value, it really depends on your case and your data.

Comment: its mainly the UniqueKey but it didn't work with me  i tried putting it in almost all of the widgets so that even if the level was wrong then it will work in some case and it didn't rebuild the images so if you have a better idea please share it with me

Comment: I think you are updating it wrong but I can't help you much further as you said your tried setstste and streams and futures, I think you are using them wrong, but I can't be sure as I don't have access to the full code, and honestly I don't have the time to do a full code review

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is usefull to you, but maybe you can fetch the image only when there is an active connection. https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity

Pseudo code:

```
Stream<List<Companies>> $ companiesStream = $connectivitySteam()
  .filter(x => x.hadInternet)
  .take(1)
  .switchMap(x => fetchCompanies)
```

Something like this will only fetch the companies when there is an internet connection.

Comment: the problem only happens if your internet connection is weak or if you suddenly disconnected from the internet while the future builder is building assets  i just want to reload the page or remove the images and refetch them will work as well i am stuck in this problem for 5 days XD